# R: Incorrect encoding of narrow space in data frame and resulting .csv

Tags: r, character-encoding

I scraped data and received some character variables containing a narrow no break space (unicode U+202F). The resulting character variable shows up fine in R if it is in a vector. For example, the return of test shows up with a narrow space in the console:

```html
test <- "variable1&#8239;variable2"
<br>
test
```

(html code here because the code environment does not show the narrow space)

However, if I add the vector to a list/data frame/tibble, it shows up as `variable1<U+202F>variable2` . If I save this data frame as a csv file with `fileEncoding = "UTF-8"` and open it with the corresponding encoding,  still shows up in the observations. My workaround right now is to use gsub but I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with using `gsub`, or regex for that matter?

Comment: It is error prone and a workaround rather than a solution.

Answer (score 3):

The offender is `format.default`:

```
test <- "variable1\u202Fvariable2"
print(test)
[1] "variable1 variable2"
format(test)
#[1] "variable1<U+202F>variable2"
```

`format` gets called by `format.data.frame` which in turn is called by `print.data.frame`.

A solution might be to define a character method:

```
format.character <- function(x, ...) x

DF <- data.frame(x = 1:5) #beware of stringsAsFactors
DF$test <- test
DF #spaces are actually thin spaces in R console
#  x                test
#1 1 variable1 variable2
#2 2 variable1 variable2
#3 3 variable1 variable2
#4 4 variable1 variable2
#5 5 variable1 variable2
```

Obviously, such a simple method will break functions relying on other `format` arguments.

OTOH, why do you care how thin spaces are printed?

Comment: I do not care how they are printed but the observations in the resulting csv file should exactly be the scraped text, i.e. `"variable1 variable2"`, not `"variable1<U+202F>variable2"`

Comment: Well, you are obviously in encoding hell. I don't know how to fix the file export.

Comment: Would it be possible to post reproducible code including the scraping ?

Answer (score 1):

Anbody having the same problem: There is a package called `textclean` which replaces or removes non-ascii characters by `replace_non_ascii()`.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to convert all unicode characters to blank using `gsub`:

```
text <- "variable1\u202Fvariable2"
new_text <- gsub("[^\x20-\x7E]", " ", text)
```

Here I match the negation of all commonly used ASCII characters, ranging from hex code 20 (SPACE) to 7E (~). The disadvantage of this method is that you might unintentionally remove more than what you wish, but you can always add exclusions to the character class.

**Output:**

```
> format(text)
[1] "variable1<U+202F>variable2"

> format(new_text)
[1] "variable1 variable2"
```